# Replacing old thermostat with 2 white wires for zone boiler heat

Tags: thermostat

I am replacing our basement thermostat that had a white and orange wire together and a white and blue wire together. That is all there is. I ham trying to put in a heat only non programmable honeywell  thermostat. It shows where to put the blue wire and orange wire but what do I do with the 2 white wires?

Comment: Can you post photos of how the wires are hooked up to the other end? Where on this planet are you, anyway?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one pair of wires to control heat only.  It sounds like they used phone wire to run the stat. The phone is so light that they paired the wires together to reduce the voltage drop.  Keep them in the pair format.

Comment: If I keep them paired what terminals do I use. There is B,O,G,Y,W, and the R and RC which I know I wont use.

Comment: At the thermostat if you connect he two wires together the heat system should start.  Those two wires will go to R and W on the stat.  When the stat senses at drop in room temperature below the home owner has called for it will close the contact between R and W.